# How do I run PovRay on MacOS (Catalina 10.15.2)?

Tags: macos

after some time I tried to install the newest PovRay (3.6 or 3.7) on my Mac.

Before, I only installed PovRay through ports and all went fine, I could use a full PovRay environment. If I try it now, PovRay won't start on Mac, it will crash, complaining something about "could not start in MainThread" or so. However, I´ve uninstalled PovRay with "port" because it was only the renderer, but before there also were provided a GUI which made development in PovRay very comfortable.

Because this GUI was not provided by "port", I tried to download PovRay from poverty.org: they provide a seemingly PovRay-"distribution" but only for Windows, I didn't found the MacOS Distribution. I downloaded some sort of distribution from another source, but that didn't do anything.

Then I´ve downloaded the PovRay source like in the "good old linux days" and tried to compile the source on my own, like in the good old days. Even that failed. And this is the first time I could cross-compile a linux source code since several decades. It seems as if MacOS is no longer fully supported by open-source (?).

However, while PovRay can be installed with "port", only the renderer is installed, it seems as if MacOS is not really supported by open source. Or is there an other distribution where the whole PovRay is provided?

Answer (score 1):

1) In the meantime I´ve found a distribution which would work "out of the box": http://megapov.inetart.net/

I do not now this site, but it is working so far with Povray 3.8

2) I have also found an explanation and a workaround for the crash of PovRay in the terminal: there is assumable a new security "feature" in Mac OS now which prevents spawned threads to access resources on the computer like the (Desktop) window and main processes: if PovRay is rendering and trying to start the rendering window, Mac OS raises a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" and the process crashes. In case of PovRay, there is a "workaround" in prohibiting PovRay to write to the Desktop:

> povray DISPLAY=off scene.pov

It simply renders without displaying the rendered scene to the desktop